# Razor MVC Jquery escaping string from c#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

Iam using:

```
@:$('.ccuListView tr:last').after('<tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr></tr>');
```

Will result in SyntaxError: (inside of my console, FireFOx)

> expected expression, got '&''

What to do here, do I need to escape something  ?

Comment: `tr` as child of `tr` ????

Comment: What version of MVC are you using? I believe this was fixed in MVC5. You could use `@Html.Raw()` as a workaround